# Library works with Clang but not with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, clang

Why does [this library](https://code.google.com/p/libdivsufsort/) work perfectly with Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79), while merely including the header file causes an error with GCC 4.9?

Minimal source file that produces the error:

```
#include <divsufsort.h>

int main() {  
  return 0;
}
```

The error I get with GCC 4.9:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:74:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:86:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:94:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:108:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:123:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:137:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:152:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
 ^
/usr/local/include/divsufsort.h:169:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
 DIVSUFSORT_API
```

Comment: That's not a library; it is a header.  There's a difference. A header is source code; a library is object code.  (Yes, Boost confuses things by having 'header-only libraries'.)  Are you compiling it as C++ or as C?  Is it intended to be compiled as C++ or as C?  Please — choose the correct language and do not dual tag.

Comment: Show your compilation commands.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Many well-eritten C headers are  C++-compatible, that's what `#ifdef __cplusplus` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you need to run `./configure` on the libdivsufsort directory again with the CC environment variable pre-set for the compiler you intend to use. (CC for "c" code. CXX for c++ code). Then rebuild.

```
cd ~/libdivsufsort-2.0.1
make clean
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
./configure
make
```

Try this link: [Configuring for a compiler different than the default while running configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435816/configuring-for-a-compiler-different-than-the-default-while-running-configure)