# Install RODBC Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

Tags: r, macos, rodbc

Fresh install at 10.12.1 with upgrades to 10.12.3.

I did the `brew install unixodbc`.

I then tried R CMD `INSTALL  RODBC_1.3-14.tar.gz`
with error:

`` checking for gcc... /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/7f/3n9kqyy13glcwlrx7h8cb5dc0000gn/T/RtmpYQnA2y/R.INSTALL354a771740af/RODBC':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’ ``

I then unpacked RODBC and tried to `./configure` and got the following error message in the log:

`configure:2690: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -v >&5
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
configure:2701: $? = 0
configure:2690: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:2701: $? = 1
configure:2690: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang: error: no input files
configure:2701: $? = 1
configure:2721: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2743: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -I.  conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:2747: $? = 1
configure:2785: result: no`

Comment: I am getting an error with lomp not found, but I thought clang 3.9.1 had the openmp libraries.                                                                             "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.1/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o a.out /var/folders/7f/3n9kqyy13glcwlrx7h8cb5dc0000gn/T/conftest-c7544c.o -lomp -lSystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.1/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lomp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue For me, the problem was that the R installer was relying on the clang compiler that shipped with OS X (Sierra, 10.12.4), which [does not support openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra).

I also couldn't get any of the usual means for specifying a different compiler to `configure` to work (such as examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435816/configuring-for-a-compiler-different-than-the-default-while-running-configure)) because, as it turns out, RODBC's configure script is hard-coded to use the compilers and lib/include paths specified by your R installation, which are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921153/c-compilation-flags-from-r).

I was able to resolve the problem by editing `~/.R/Makevars` to point to a version of `gcc` I installed via macports (`sudo port install gcc6`), as such:

```
CC=/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-6 -fopenmp
CXX=/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
```

Then the normal installation process (`R CMD INSTALL ./RODBC_1.3-15.tar.gz`) worked as expected.